# JAVA which elements of a list are not in another list

Tags: java

Is there a quick way to see if elements of a list are in another list and if not put those elements not in list B into a list

```
List<String> listA;  // [1, 2, 5, 8]
List<String> listB;  // [2, 4, 6, 8]

5// is not!!
```

Comment: Are the lists `listA` and `listB` always sorted first?

Comment: Hint: you're interested in *sets* more than lists... even if you happen to start off with lists. (Although List.removeAll could be useful too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... I would do it like this :

```
List<String> listA;  // [1, 2, 5, 8]
List<String> listB;  // [2, 4, 6, 8]

// Now do a removeAll which will remove all the values from `Collection 1` that are present in `Collection 2`. You need import `java.utils.Collection` for this.

listA.removeAll(listB) // This will return make listA a list containing only 5 to you.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Sets for this.

No reason for going to all this trouble, when the Set interface was created for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Set for this. The add() method return a boolean based on your exact requirement - true if the element did not exist and it could be added, false otherwise (and does not add the element).